# AeroGearOAuth2 Swift Retrieve Google Contacts

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, google-contacts-api

I am trying to make a contact management/social network application and am using the AeroGearOAuth2 after following a tutorial from the [Ray Wenderlich website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/99431/oauth-2-with-swift-tutorial). I have modified it to try and first authenticate the user, then using a closure in swift I am attempting to retrieve this user's contacts. I have used the google OAuth2 playground to play around with the scopes and GET url's but keep receiving the value of 'nil' on my inner response. I feel like I must jsut be forgetting something that is painfully obvious. I wasn't entirely sure how to attach the header of 'Gdata-version:3' so I winged that. This could be the problem. Here is my function to retrieve contacts:

```
    @IBAction func getGoogleContacts(sender: AnyObject) {
    let googleConfig = GoogleConfig(
        clientId: ${MY_CLIENT_ID},                               
        scopes:["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email","https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"])

    let gdModule = AccountManager.addGoogleAccount(googleConfig)    
    self.http.authzModule = gdModule                                
    let headers = ["Gdata-Version ": "3.0"]
    let contactsUrl:String = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"
    let emailUrl:String = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";

    self.http.GET(emailUrl,completionHandler: {(response, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            self.presentAlert("Error", message: "\(error!.localizedDescription) + \(response)")
        } else {
            let userEmail: AnyObject! = response!["email"]!
            self.http.GET(contactsUrl,parameters:headers, completionHandler: {
            (response2,error2) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    self.presentAlert("Error",message:"\ (error2!.localizedDescription)" )
                }else {
                      println(response2)
                 }
             })

            self.presentAlert("Success", message: "Successfully retrieved contact: + \(userEmail)")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Google has removed the support for client flow OAuth2. Now your application needs to display the consent URL to the user, and if the user give your app the grants, use the received token to make calls to the API.

Comment: so this does happen. the outer function calls "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo" and retrieves the token. my understanding was that using /default/  for the subsequent request to "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full"  will use the currently authorized user by passing the token along.

Comment: Hello @kinghenry14 can u share your code how u fetched successfully contacts ? that will be really helpful.